# Expand search div to the button

Tags: html, css

I've HTML structure like following

```
<div class="box-search-select">

  <div class="search-left">
    <input id="search" type="text">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

and CSS as following

```
.box-search-select{
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.search-left{
  float:left;
  width: 90%;
}
.search-left input{
  width:100%;
}
button{
  float:right;
}
```

Output : (Normal screen size)
[image]

I want to expand "search-left" div width to the Search button.

Which should work properly for fluid responsive layouts too.

Here I've created fiddle if you wish to play : https://jsfiddle.net/j7g8143a/1

Now if I decrease the width of screen then the search button move to next line like following picture

[image]

but I want the "search-left" div to automatically adjust it's width according to screen size like following picture.

[image]

I need only CSS solution without using any media queries

**EDIT:** It should have to be compatible with IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution with demo and **it will be work on IE9 also**:

```
<div class="box-search-select">
  <div class="search-left">
  <input id="search" type="text">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
</div>

.box-search-select {
  padding: 20px 68px 20px 0; /* give padding-right equal to button witdh */
  position: relative;
}

.search-left input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background: #cccccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/0u83dbm7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
.box-search-select {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.search-left {
  flex: 1;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-search-select">
  <div class="search-left"><input id="search" type="text"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

You can also use CSS tables

```css
.box-search-select {
  display: table;
}
.search-left,
button {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.search-left {
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-search-select">
  <div class="search-left"><input id="search" type="text"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nenad, But Flexbox  are not supported in IE 9 (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) so I'm afried to use it as I've to implement it on live project.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nenad Vracar.

Answer (score 0):

Its gonna work I think

```
<div class="box-search-select">

  <div class="search-left" style="width:80%">
    <input id="search" type="text">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
<style>
#search{
    width:100%;
}
.box-search-select{
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.search-left{
  float:left;
  width: 90%;
}
.search-left input{
  width:100%;
}
button{
  float:right;
}
</style>
```

please let me know if this is not the expected output.

Comment: Sorry @vivek, Not expected output.Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: Same as this https://jsfiddle.net/j7g8143a/2/ (Thanks to Nenad) but without using media queries and JS/jQuery with IE9 competiblity.

Answer (score 0):

Put your input and button inside the div and use display:flex

```
.box-search-select{
  padding:20px 0;
  float:left;
  width:100%
}
.search-left{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;

}
.search-left input{
  width:100%
}
button{
  float:right;
}

<div class="box-search-select">

  <div class="search-left">
    <input id="search" type="text">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
  </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: It won't be compatible with IE 9. Thanks anyway for trying.